# jQuery mouseover and mouseout not functioning as desired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having an issue where jquery mouseover and mouseout do not work with the css function..
I am trying to have transition effects for buttons on an image slider.

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="hero">
    <div id="next">
        <img class="nxt" src="http://www.uk-timber.co.uk/ebay2014/images/jsSlider/next.png"/>
    </div>
    <!--END--Next-->

    <div id="prev">
        <img class="prv" src="http://www.uk-timber.co.uk/ebay2014/images/jsSlider/prev.png"/>
    </div>
    <!--END--Prev-->

    <div id="slider">
        <img src="http://www.uk-timber.co.uk/ebay2014/images/jsSlider/slides/slide1.png"/>
        <img src="http://www.uk-timber.co.uk/ebay2014/images/jsSlider/slides/slide2.png"/>
        <img src="http://www.uk-timber.co.uk/ebay2014/images/jsSlider/slides/slide3.png"/>              
    </div>
    <!--END--Slider-->
</div>
<!--END--Hero-->
```

My CSS Code:

```
#hero {
    width: 944px; height: 360px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;

}

#slider {
    width: 944px; height: 360px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;       
}

#next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

and finally my JS Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#hero").mouseover(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find("#next").css(
            "transition":"all 0.2s ease-in",
            "opacity":"1"
        );
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find("#next").css(
            "transition":"all 0.2s ease-out",
            "opacity":"0.3"
        );
    });
});
```

Please bare in mind i am new to javascript and jquery so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It should be: `.css({transition:"all 0.2s ease-in", opacity:1})` etc.. Now you should firstly learn how to debug javascript. BTW, `$this.find("#next")` doesn't make sense as IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: doesn't work how exactly, what is happening, and what are you expecting. Just posting some code and "doesn't work" tells us nothing ?

Comment: And there's a `ease-in-out` in CSS that does both without javascript ?

Comment: can you post your fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

Try mouseleave function.

```
 $(function(){
     $("#hero").mouseover(function () {
         $this = $(this);
         $this.find("#next").css({
             "transition":"all 0.2s ease-in",
             "opacity":"1"
         });
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find("#next").css({
            "transition":"all 0.2s ease-out",
            "opacity":"0.3"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax for css method but good catch regarding mouseleave

Comment: If you're switching to mouseleave, using mouseenter would make sense as well, but how could you possibly know that mouseover and mouseout isn't exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I've put your code in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fnv7w/). This won't work.

Then I cleaned it up a bit and got rid of some syntax errors [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fnv7w/3) and voila: it works.

Note: If you're only going to change the opacity, you better do it with just CSS:

```
#next{
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

#hero:hover #next{
    opacity: 1;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

/*DON'T FORGET TO PREFIX THE TRANSITION-ATTRIBUTES*/
```